# Can't check checkbox in Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, rspec, capybara

I just did a `save_and_open_page`, so here's the html of what I'm trying to click for an integration test.

```
<input id="tos" name="tos" type="checkbox" value="{:id=>"tos"}">
<label for="tos">I have read and agree to the <a href="/termsofservice" style="color:#428bca" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a>.</label>
```

And the code:

```
<%= check_box_tag :tos, id: "tos" %>
<%= label_tag "tos", "I have read and agree to the #{link_to 'Terms of Service', terms_path, { style: "color:#428bca", target: "_blank" }}.".html_safe %>
```

Here are all the FAILED ways of checking the thing that I have tried

```
find(:xpath, "//*[@id='tos']").set(true)
check 'tos'
find("#tos").set(true)
check 'I have read and agree to the Terms of Service'
check 'I have read and agree to the "<a href="/termsofservice" style="color:#428bca" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a>".'            
find(:css, "#tos[value='{:id=>&quot;tos&quot;}']").set(true)
find(:css, "#tos[value='{:id=>'tos'}']").set(true)
```

Why is this so hard...

OK more context per the comments:

The full flow of this spec is:

```
      describe "something" do

        before do
          visit '/original'
          page.check("tos")
          fill_in 'signup_email1', :with => "test@example.com"
          click_button 'lend'
          save_and_open_page
          fill_in 'inventory_1', :with => 1
          click_button 'submit_lend'
        end

        it "should achieve some result" do
        ...
        end

      end
```

After every attempt I've tried so far, the error message is just

```
Failure/Error: fill_in 'inventory_1', :with => 1
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find field "inventory_1"
```

Because it's reflecting that when then the `click_button 'lend'` happens, the user is not directed to a page to lend things where there is a `inventory_1` because instead they get the `/original` page re-rendered with an error (confirmed via `save_and_open_page`) stating that Terms of Service must be agreed to before continuing.

Comment: You didn't show error messages for any of your attempts. Try `page.check("tos")` and show the output.

Comment: Tried, didn't work, I posted more context and error messages, sorry I left that out because it seems like it wouldn't be too helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it working... perhaps at best this is a reminder of bad dev practices. Right after I wrote out the code for the page, I wrote my tests (reverse I know...). In this case, as I wrote the test and wrote out `check 'tos'`, I went back into the view and added `id: 'tos'` to the `check_box_tag`. That was the mistake, `check_box_tag`'s second parameter is the value, so by adding that I made the `check_box_tag` always take on a value of `tos` rather than `1` if checked and `0` if not.

Basically, in the spec, `check 'tos'` works fine if in the view you just have `<%= check_box_tag "tos %>`